# How I can make drop down menu from my categories mysql table only show if parent_id is not 0

Tags: php, html, mysql, dropdown

So hey there as the title said I am looking for away to make my categories with subcategories. I been looking in stackoverflow for what I need but none has help me of the examples..

Here is how my table look like
[image]
So I know what I want and what I need but I have no idea how I can do that possible

1. I have to `SELECT * FROM categories ORDER by position ASC`
2. I have to check if `parent_id` is bigger then 0.
3. I have to remove the `parent_id` from my navbar and show them only under the category name where it should be by `dropdown menu` .

But I have no idea how I could do all of that ..

Here is how I am selecting only my categories and display them

```
                  $catsq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categories ORDER by position ASC");
                    while($catinfo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($catsq)) {
                      echo '
                         <li class="nav-item'.(isset($_GET["cat"]) && $_GET["cat"]==$catinfo["id"] ? " active" : "").'">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="./index.php?cat='.$catinfo["id"].'">'.$catinfo["name"].'</a>
                         </li>
                      ';
                    }
```

and it's look like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="cat=1">TestCat</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="cat=2">TestCat2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="cat=3">TestSub</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but I want It to look like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class=""><a href="cat=1">TestCat</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown ">
        //TestCat2 have to doing nothing always.
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TestCat2</i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="cat=3">TestSub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when the `parent_id` is more then 0..

If anyone can help me with this would be great..

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: If there are only two levels, you don’t need to worry about recursion, just do a nested loop. You can either build a two dimensional array (`$result[$parent_id][$id] = $name`) or make database calls from within a loop of top level categories. (select *from categories where parent_id='0', foreach..., select * from categories where parent_id=?) where ? is $id

Comment: Well yes there going to be only two levels normal `<li>` and else `dropdown` and by your way I have try it day ago as I have seen it here as example but it does not really help me it always show the dropdown menu even if there is sub cat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take:

1. Build an array
2. Nested queries
3. Recursion

#### Array

This approach builds a data structure that you can iterate through in your view. [Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4249da36aff6aa1ab9f073749ab7f3c743b1d1f6)

```
<?php
// get db connection...

// create categories array
$stmt = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY position ASC");
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    // $category[ $row['parent_id] ][ $row['id'] ] = $row; // use if you need to access other fields in addition to name
    $category[ $row['parent_id] ][ $row['id'] ] = $row['name'];
}

// other php stuff...

?>
<html>

... snip ...

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach($category[0] as $id => $name): ?>
        <?php if( isset( $category[$id]) ): ?>

          <li class="dropdown ">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?= $name ?></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach($category[$id] as $sub_id => $sub_name): ?>

                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="?cat=<?= $sub_id ?>" ><?= $sub_name ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
          </li>

        <?php else: ?>  

            <li class="">
                <a href="?cat=<?= $id ?>"><?= $name ?></a>
            </li>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

#### Nested Queries

This method is easiest to display using an imaginary class that does all the sql stuff behind the scenes.  For the sake of argument, we will assume a class `Category` that has a method named `listByParent($parent_id)` which returns a list of rows having the designated parent_id.

```
<?php
$cat = new Category();

$topLevel = $cat->listByParent(0);
?>
<html>

... snip ...

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach( $topLevel as $topRow ): ?>

        <!-- note, this method is run on every iteration of top level categories -->
        <?php $subRows = $cat->listByParent($topRow['id']) ?>

        <?php if( count($subRows)): ?>
        <li class="dropdown ">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?= $topRow['name'] ?></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach($subRows as $row): ?>

                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="?cat=<?= $row['id'] ?>" ><?= $row['name'] ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

                </ul>
          </li>

        <?php else: ?>  

            <li class="">
                <a href="?cat=<?= $topRow['id'] ?>"><?= $topRow['name'] ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

#### Recursion

Using recursion would allow you to have “unlimited” levels of subcategories. However, it’s a level of complexity that does not seem warranted in this case. But should you want to pursue it, note that the best way to approach it would be to make a template for the html that could be accessed programatically, with `$cat->findByParent()` being a key player...

Comment: Okey thanks a lot the 1st method its look nice for me I would go ahead with it but there is just one thing, all of them become with `ARRAY` so far I can see there is no reason for that.

Comment: Okey I have fix it now its working more then great, thanks for your help sir.
What I have add is 

`$name=$row['name'];`

`$category[$catinfo['parent_id'] ][ $catinfo['id'] ]  = $name;`

and then the problem has fixed 

thank you.

Comment: Oops, I stuck all the data into the array, instead of just the name.  That would have  been useful if you had more information you needed to access, but all you need is the name. I'll update the answer, thanks.

Comment: Yep thank you, you save my work with like 2 days maybe.. ;d